# Getting data from textboxes and multiply

Tags: c#, json, double, type-conversion

I have:

textbox1.text == 1.4087
textbox2.text == 521.54

It's not hardcoded, I get it from JSON. Anyway, I want to multiply these two numbers.

I use this code:

```
double curr = 0.0;
double price = 0.0;
double multiply = 0.0;

double.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out curr);
double.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out price);

multiply = curr * price;

textBox3.Text = multiply.ToString();
```

I also tried with `Convert.ToDouble` still no luck.
I always get 0 in textBox3. Apparently the strings are not recognized as double. But they are. Any ideas? Thanks!

EDIT:  From JSON:

```
{"high": "567.88", "last": "543.95", "timestamp": "1394987785",
```

I'm using this code to get what i need:

```
Regex expression = new Regex(@"last"":\s""(?<Identifier>[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)");
      var results = expression.Matches(Cryp);
                foreach (Match match in results)
                {
                    textBox1.Text = match.Groups["Identifier"].Value;
                }
```

Any issues here?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

```
double.TryParse(textBox1,NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint,
                                 CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out curr);
double.TryParse(textBox2.Text,NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint,
                                 CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out price);
multiply = curr * price;
```

Comment: @user3379278: `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` should work IMO, which culture you are in?

Comment: @user3379278: you mean with `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`?

Comment: @Sudhaker Could you please explain what's the problem?

Comment: @user3379278: i suspect that it is because of your cultural settings. remember that floating point numbers behave differently based on different cultures, so you need to parse the given floating point value as invariant cuture to make it neutral

Answer (score 0):

I would assume one of the TryParse calls fails resulting in it keeping a value of 0 so regardless of what the working one is, you're going to get 0 for a result.

I just wrote up a basic ASP.NET application with three textboxes and then just pasted your code without changing anything into the event handler for a submit button. Manually typing the two numbers you provided gave the correct answer of `734.693398` in TextBox3. Your inputs must be off.